# Mysql Innodb hangs on Table Level Lock

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I have a production system with 10,000 queries/second. I recently updated to MySQL v5.5 and am now facing an issue: my `InnoDB` tables get locked all of a sudden.

```
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO P.S (PREFERENCE, PROPERTY_TYPE, RES_COM, BEDROOM_NUM, BATHROOM_NUM, PRIC
Updating                     | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE property.PROFILE SET PASSWORD=AES_ENCRYPT(XXX) WHERE PROFILEID='4987835'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE property.PROFILE SET PASSWORD=AES_ENCRYPT(XXXX) WHERE PROFILEID='5405007'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET SCREENING = 'N' WHERE PROFILEID='560353'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET PASSWORD=AES_ENCRYPT(XXXX) WHERE PROFILEID='5405009'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET PASSWORD=AES_ENCRYPT(XXXXX) WHERE PROFILEID='4987835'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET PASSWORD=AES_ENCRYPT(XXXX) WHERE PROFILEID='540502'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.S SET ACTIVATED = 'Y', SCREENING = 'N' WHERE  SPID = '8252535'
Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE P.P SET MODIFY_DATE = now() WHERE PROFILEID = '3481803'
```

What could be the problem here?

Output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%';` below:

```
+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                   |
+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| have_innodb                     | YES                     |
| ignore_builtin_innodb           | OFF                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing        | ON                      |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index      | ON                      |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size | 134217728               |
| innodb_autoextend_increment     | 8                       |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        | 1                       |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances    | 5                       |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size         | 3221225472              |
| innodb_change_buffering         | all                     |
| innodb_checksums                | ON                      |
| innodb_commit_concurrency       | 50                      |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets      | 500                     |
| innodb_data_file_path           | ibdata1:100M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir            | mysql5/data/            |
| innodb_doublewrite              | ON                      |
| innodb_fast_shutdown            | 1                       |
| innodb_file_format              | Antelope                |
| innodb_file_format_check        | ON                      |
| innodb_file_format_max          | Antelope                |
| innodb_file_per_table           | ON                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  | 2                       |
| innodb_flush_method             | O_DIRECT                |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted     | OFF                     |
| innodb_force_recovery           | 0                       |
| innodb_io_capacity              | 200                     |
| innodb_large_prefix             | OFF                     |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout        | 100                     |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                     |
| innodb_log_buffer_size          | 8388608                 |
| innodb_log_file_size            | 536870912               |
| innodb_log_files_in_group       | 2                       |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir       | ./                      |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      | 75                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag            | 0                       |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups      | 1                       |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct           | 37                      |
| innodb_old_blocks_time          | 0                       |
| innodb_open_files               | 300                     |
| innodb_purge_batch_size         | 100                     |
| innodb_purge_threads            | 0                       |
| innodb_random_read_ahead        | OFF                     |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold     | 56                      |
| innodb_read_io_threads          | 4                       |
| innodb_replication_delay        | 0                       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout      | OFF                     |
| innodb_rollback_segments        | 64                      |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay          | 6                       |
| innodb_stats_method             | nulls_equal             |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata        | ON                      |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages       | 8                       |
| innodb_strict_mode              | OFF                     |
| innodb_support_xa               | ON                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops          | 30                      |
| innodb_table_locks              | ON                      |
| innodb_thread_concurrency       | 0                       |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay       | 10000                   |
| innodb_use_native_aio           | ON                      |
| innodb_use_sys_malloc           | ON                      |
| innodb_version                  | 1.1.8                   |
| innodb_write_io_threads         | 4                       |
+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you add table definition (including the engine - the tables may be converted to isam ones)

Comment: All tables in question which are in locked state are innodb

Comment: ---TRANSACTION 5D4ABD70, not started
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
MySQL thread id 8110887, OS thread handle 0x2ab100001940, query id 112628214 Waiting for table level lock
UPDATE P.P SET MODIFY_DATE = now() WHERE PROFILEID = '5258157'

Comment: @ eggyal No DDL statement was executed.

Comment: http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.in/2007/06/innodb-table-locks.html

LOCK TABLES acquires two locks on each table if innodb_table_locks=1 (the default). In addition to a table lock on the MySQL layer, it also acquires an InnoDB table lock. Versions of MySQL before 4.1.2 did not acquire InnoDB table locks; the old behavior can be selected by setting innodb_table_locks=0. If no InnoDB table lock is acquired, LOCK TABLES completes even if some records of the tables are being locked by other transactions.

http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.in/2007/06/innodb-table-locks.html

Comment: @user1915595: Can you provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE P.P`?